# Pip Package dependency overriding specified version in requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, jinja2, python-venv

I got a Flask App and installed the dependencies out of the requirements.txt.
I got the following error when running my App:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe'
```

MarkupSafe is a package required by Jinja2 which in turn is required by Flask.

I soon found out that downgrading MarkupSafe from version 2.1.1 to 2.0.1 fixes the issue, and I adapted my requirements.txt:

```
MarkupSafe==2.0.1 # Newer version causes errors
rpi-ws281x==4.3.3
Flask==2.0.3
Flask-SocketIO==5.1.1
```

But after installing, I find out that the Jinja2 installing process overrides my specified version of MarkupSafe and I again end up with version 2.1.1. I know about the `force reinstall` option of pip but wondered if there is a better approach.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use pipenv: https://pipenv.pypa.io/.

At least some time ago, Pip used to have some flaws in solving multiple packages dependencies. I now saw an update note on their documentation that seems to tackle the problem; haven't tested yet. Pipenv would solve the dependencies graph just fine. That was one of the reason I started using Pipenv.

Please, have a look at the following pages:

- https://realpython.com/pipenv-guide/ (pipenv; your scenario)
- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/dependency-resolution/#backtracking (pip; recent update)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/55826767/687896 (similar question)

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this. Actually, I solved my problem by just bumping flask to the newest version, but I wondered what one would do if that's not an option.

Comment: @ningelsohn just updated my answer with some better info. Cheers